# What to split or re.compile

Tags: python

i want to remove /1693798184 in link id but I can't delete it with python program

```
import requests, re

id = /subtitles/bullet-train/english/2894262/1693798184


id = re.compile('(.+?.+?.+?.+?)/.+?').findall(id)[0]    
#id = id.split('/')[0] 
print('id', id)
```

Comment: do `re.sub("/\\d+$", "", id)`

Comment: `os.path.dirname(id)`

Comment: This code doesn't run as is. Did you mean to quote the id value? Why do you need `requests`? What did you expect `split('/')[0]` to return if you wanted `[:-1]` instead?

Comment: thanks!
even that I spent all night its success

Comment: id ['', 'subtitles', 'bullet-train', 'english', '2898975']
url https://indexsubtitle.cc['', 'subtitles', 'bullet-train', 'english', '2898975']

Comment: id = id.split('/')[:-1] gives me a list

Comment: To use split, you need to re-join the List elements : `'/'.join(id.split('/')[:-1])`

Answer (score 0):

Use `rsplit` with max split of 1 and get the first element:

```
id = '/subtitles/bullet-train/english/2894262/1693798184'
id = id.rsplit('/',1)[0]
print('id', id)

# /subtitles/bullet-train/english/2894262
```

or use regex suggested by [@onyambu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8380272/onyambu) in comment section:

```
import re

id = '/subtitles/bullet-train/english/2894262/1693798184'
id = re.sub("/\\d+$", "", id)
print('id', id)

# /subtitles/bullet-train/english/2894262
```